# Изменение по клику внутри цикла

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, всем.
В задании нужно вывести товар циклом и внутри информации о каждом товаре есть счетчик, который по клику увеличивает товар на 1. Когда кликаю на один товар изменяется значение у всех товаров. Не пойму как сделать условие, чтобы действовал только на один товар. Ниже то, как делаю(извините, если неправильно форматирую):

```
<?php
    $dbconnect;
    $var_order_id = (int)$_GET['ordid'];
    $c_result = pg_query("SELECT i.image, i.name, c.prod_price, c.prod_count, c.id_cart
                          FROM cart as c  join items as i  on  i.id = c.prod_id  WHERE  c.order_id = '$var_order_id'");
    $div_numc = pg_num_rows($c_result);     
    for($i=0; $i < $div_numc; $i++){
        $cart_catalog = pg_fetch_array($c_result);
        $id_cart = $cart_catalog['id_cart'];
        //При клике на кнопку делаю вот этот апдейт.
        if(isset($_POST['subplus'])){
            $update_query = pg_query("UPDATE cart SET prod_count = prod_count+1, 
                                      sum_price = prod_price*(prod_count+1) WHERE id_cart = '$id_cart'
                                      returning  prod_count");  
            $v_prod_count = pg_fetch_array($update_query);
            $var_prod_count = $v_prod_count['prod_count'];
        }
?>
```

Здесь html с тем, что вывожу.

```
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: а у тебя точно при "UPDATE cart SET prod_count = prod_count+1, 
    sum_price = prod_price*(prod_count+1) WHERE id_cart = '$id_cart'
    returning  prod_count" изменяется одно ? ты попробуй просто выбрать по этому условию и посмотри что будет

Comment: тебе лучше передавать в $_POST id товара и твой subplus

Comment: jashka, прости за непонятливость, немного не понял. Я пробую кликать по счетчику одного товара, а меняется у всех, если ставлю запрос внутри цикла. Если за циклом, то меняется только у последней записи, что бы ни кликал((

Comment: jashka, subplus - это у меня сабмит, я его постом передаю. Пробовал еще id товара прибавлять к условию запроса. Все равно меняет у всех.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в своём коде циклом обходите все элементы корзины и, если в $_POST есть нужный флаг, увеличиваете количество. У каждого элемента. В этом и проблема. Вам нужно передавать на сервер id товара, который вы хотите обновить и либо выбирать только этот элемент корзины, если остальные в вашем коде не нужны, либо внутри цикла проверять не только флаг, но и совпадение id:

```
if (isset($_POST['subplus']) && $_POST['item_id'] == $id_cart) {}
```

Comment: Я добавил пример, как это должно выглядеть на стороне сервера.

Comment: Попробовал при клике отправить скрытым инпутом id, но посылается он из цикла, поэтому, все равно относится ко всем товарам корзины((

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Comment: А где у вас форма сама? Вам бы подучить основы html... На каждый товар должна быть своя форма.

Comment: Наверное, можно, я не очень понимаю, о чём вы говорите. Пожалуйста, не нужно устраивать чат в комментариях: если у вас есть новый вопрос - оформите его в виде полноценного вопроса. Что касается текущего вопроса - я не могу вам помочь, поскольку не вижу весь релевантный код. У вас там может быть всё, что угодно.

Comment: Алексей Уколов, спасибо за уделенное время. Думаю, в рамках этого ресурса не получится разобраться.